# Mongoose Ref User Object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I hope everyone learning something today. I need some help. I have a Gift model which looks something like this:

```
   let giftSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
       gift: String,
       date: {
           type: Date
       },
       giftDescription: String,
       giftAmount: String,
       giftCode: String,
       redeemCode: String,
       passCode: String,
       senderFirstName: String,
       senderLastName: String,
       giftMessage: String,
       user: {
           id: {
               type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
               ref: 'User'
           },
           username: String
       }
   });

   module.exports = mongoose.model('Gift', giftSchema);
```

This is my user model:

```
   const mongoose = require('mongoose'),
         passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');

   let UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
       firstName: String,
       lastName: String,
       alaisFirstName: String,
       alaisLastName: String,
       username: String,
       password: String,
       isAdmin: Boolean,
       addressLine1: String,
       addressLine2: String,
       city: String,
       state: String,
       zipCode: String
   });

   UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

   module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

I have pretty much 2 users, and no guest. The admin sends gifts to a user. So as an admin, on the new route, I need to send something to the user. However, in my field: *for* ( think gmail search field ) I will be searching for either firstName, lastName, alaisFirstName, and alaisLastName than sending the gift to the user.

How could I model that? I cant do it by `type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,`  because the admin is the one sending it to the user, but I want something similar to that.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm really not clear on what you're trying to do

Comment: I need to submit a form, and add some sort of relationship between the gift model and the user model.

The the admin user creates the /gifts/new and the user gets a notification to accept or decline the gift.

Comment: Why don't you do some logic in you route  when you look up the user to see if `isAdmin` is true or not.